# Second lambda expression in HTML helper induces a CS0411

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Many of my HTML helpers get a lambda expression as a parameter. The helpers are called from MVC views, and the lambda expression provides the helper one of the fields from the view's underlying model. The following works fine:

```
//Helper:
public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper<T, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper,
                                                Expression<Func<T, TValue>> Parameter1
                                                /*More parameters*/)

//View:
@Html.MyHelper(m => m.Field1 /*More parameters*/)
```

I would like to add a second parameter that would  make a second field from the model available for the helper, something along this line:

```
//Helper:
public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper<T, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper,
                                                Expression<Func<T, TValue>> Parameter1,
                                                Expression<Func<T, TValue>> Parameter2
                                                /*More parameters*/)

//View:
@Html.MyHelper(m => m.Field1,
               m => m.Field2 /*More parameters*/)
```

The view generates a CS0411 compilation error (The type arguments for method '...' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.). I understand the core of the error message, but do not know how to map that to this case.

The following does compile, but I do not know how to get the two parameters at the side of the Helper method:

```
//View:
@Html.MyHelper(m => new 
               {
                   m.Field1,
                   m.Field2
               } /*More parameters*/)
```

How should I transfer more than one field (column) from the view's underlying model to an HTML helper?

Comment: Can you show the error message? I don't have all the CS's in memory ;-)

Comment: @Stefan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0411

Comment: @SnakeEyes: thanks, but I was hinting OP to include it in the question :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different type parameters involved most probably for both fields i.e. `Field1` and `Field2` while you are using same `TValue` for both.

So when we invoke the helper the types can differ of both Properties.

You will need to introduce a third type parameter in this particular case.

So try like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper<T, TParam1,TParam2>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper,
                                            Expression<Func<T, TParam1>> Parameter1,
                                            Expression<Func<T, TParam2>> Parameter2
                                            /*More parameters*/)
```

as the type of both properties can differ so a common `TValue` parameter wouldn't work.

Comment: @Ehsan_Sajjad, Thanks.